# Connection timed out after windows time changing

Tags: c#, wcf

I use `DuplexChannelFactory<>.CreateChannel` in my program for creating a connection between the server and the client. But, when I changed the operating system's time my program threw an exception.

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException: 
The operation 'Ping' could not be completed because the sessionful channel timed out waiting to receive a message.  
To increase the timeout, either set the receiveTimeout property on the binding in your configuration file,
or set the ReceiveTimeout property on the Binding directly.
```

How can I avoid this exception after changing the time on Windows?

PS. I shouldn't set a infinity timeout, cause i need to handle lost connection.

Comment: Did you try increasing the timeout?

Comment: Increasing the timeout isn't resolves problem. Question edited.

Comment: Exception thows immediately after time setting change?

Comment: Yes, it thows immediately.

Comment: Did you consder just recreating channel and proceed after CommunicationObjectAbortedException? This is common approach in network environment.